# Npm install recursively resolve dependencies

Tags: node.js, recursion

In my current React project I want to use materialize-css. It is defined in my package.json as a dependency with version ^0.98.2.

The problem is that the materialize-css folder inside the node_modules folder does not have a node_modules folder itself. I want to use the jquery dependency which is installed by materialize-css but it is not possible like this.

Is there a way to tell npm to install the dependencies of materialize-css recursively?

Comment: NPM made it so all dependencies are installed on the main node_modules to prevent two modules with the same dependency to have duplicate downloads.